# Need to display a helpText beside a tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, xml

Extension to my Previous Question which is placed here "[Hyperlink in help text which comes from XML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7855/hyperlink-in-help-text-which-comes-from-xml)"

My requirement was changed Now and it was a bit tough one.... :(
 My xml is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<HelpTextDetails>
 <BaseURL>SomeUrl here</BaseURL>
    <HelpTab TabName="Account__c" Label="Account___c">
        <TabSection Name="Settings__c">
            <HelpLink  link="Google.com" >Settings Link</HelpLink>
            <HelpVideo video="Yahoo.com" >Settings Video</HelpVideo>
        </TabSection>
         <HelpTab>
    So on like this......
<HelpTextDetails>
```

Say Account__c is a custom tab here & in that Settings__c is a sub tab.Now when I click on settings helptext should appear.My problem here is how can I compare a value which is coming from xml with a Custom tabName and again with a subtab and appropriately render the helptext.

My Apex class and Vf Page can be found here "[Hyperlink in help text which comes from XML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7855/hyperlink-in-help-text-which-comes-from-xml)"

Comment: BTW must your help data absolutely be XML format? This is the kind of thing well suited to custom labels. I get the feeling there is something bigger overall you're trying to achieve :-) worth elaborating if you can...

Comment: Can I cancel or stop bounty because this requirement no longer exist for me.Extreme Apologies for disturbing you people

Comment: Internet karma points up for grabs, this is serious business!

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

Comment: You might try deleting the question then (it's very localized anyway so I doubt it can be of help to future visitors)... But as far as I know your rep for bounty is gone.

Comment: Questions with open bounties cannot be deleted.... Getting error like this